# How to increase the waveform view range?

Tags: audacity

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audacity_waveform.html

> The default track created in Audacity when you press the record button
>   is a stereo track displayed in Waveform view with a linear vertical
>   scale running from -1.0 (negative values) to +1.0 (positive values),
>   centered on zero

Modern records often don't have enough space in Audacity and the waveform can appears as straight as an arrow. I'm asking purely from a visual standpoint, **I don't want to edit audio**.

Pixies - "What Goes Boom" waveform:

[image: What Goes Boom waveform]

*Audacity*

[image: What Goes Boom waveform]

*Adobe Audition*

Comment: There are better audio examples, but I don't own a copy of Adobe Audition. I found the AA screenshot online.

Comment: I don't know if I get it. There's nothing you can do because modern records [are deliberately crippled this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war). Few years ago [many Metallica fans discovered they preferred Guitar Hero to the official Death Magnetic CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Magnetic#Criticism_regarding_production).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: You misunderstood. My question is purely visual and I don't want to edit audio.

Comment: So what do you want it to look like?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Increase the range beyond -1.0 and +1.0. Compare the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Audacity manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audio_tracks.html#scale):

> When the mouse pointer is over the scale it changes to a magnify icon.
>
> - Left-click in the Vertical Scale for any Waveform or Spectrogram view to zoom in. […]
> - Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left-click […] to zoom out progressively. […]

The scale mentioned is the part of the screen just to the left of the waveform, where `-1.0`, `-0.5`, `0.0`, `0.5` and `1.0` are shown. You can zoom out and see the range from `-2.0` to `2.0`.

Your screenshots use different units. The `-1.0` to `1.0` scale doesn't use dB. To change the scale use [Audio Track Dropdown Menu](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audio_track_dropdown_menu.html).

Comment: Is it possible to save the vertical scale setting? Currently the range resets when restarting Audacity.

Comment: @user598527 I really don't know. You should consider asking a separate question, maybe some other user will know.